# How to call internal functions in Windows batch simultaneously?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a windows batch that reads my config files (also batch files) from within a directory. Now I want to call an internal function to process each of this config file. Since it is a for-loop, the files are processed one after another. But I want to execute each function for each file at the same time.

So far, I only found solutions for running commands simultaneously, i.e. the "start" command. But no solution for internal functions so far.

Background: Each config file contains lots of variables with different values that the function can automatically use, **without passing them on as arguments.**

Each config file contains parameters in order to execute sqlcmd with those and to process and define the output file as well. Since the variables are just too many, I don't want to handover them as arguments and therefore don't want to outsource the function into a seperate .bat file.

For reference, the code excerpt:

```
FOR %%I IN ("%path_job_sheets%\*.bat") DO (CALL "%%I" & CALL :get_period "%%I")

:get_period
CALL LOTS OF VARIABLES
CALL :get_job

:get_job
DO MORE PARAMETER CALLING
```

The ":get_period" needs to be executed but the batch should move on calling the next .bat-file.

Has anyone a solution, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `start`.

Change your file a bit, so it starts the current batch file itself (thats `%~f0`)

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="thread_job" goto :thread_job

...

FOR %%I IN ("%path_job_sheets%\*.bat") DO (
    CALL "%%I"
    CALL :get_period "%%I"
)
exit /b

...

:get_period
set "fileName=%~1"
start "Title %filename%" cmd /c "%~f0" thread_job
exit /b

:thread_job
CALL LOTS OF VARIABLES
CALL :get_job
```

If you have many jobs then it could be a good idea to use `start /b` to run all jobs in the same window.

Comment: That's actually quite smart, thanks! 
Can `:thread_job` and `:get_job` still read the variables set in %%I (=.bat file)?

Comment: Also, I need the batch to loop through all files but before exiting the loop, all jobs need to be completed. Is there an easy way to wait for the jobs in the loop to finish?